# setting up a new key value dictionary from a previous one

Tags: python, dictionary, key, haversine

Sorry for the large code dump. My problem is with my last for loop. I am attempting to set up a new dictionary, "candidates," that contains all of the possible combinations of one site with another site, mapped to the distance between them. For instance, say that site 1 has ID 1234, site 2 has ID 1235, and site 3 has ID 1236. What I want the candidates dictionary to be eventually is {'1234_1235' : distance, '1234_1236' : distance}, i.e. all possible combinations from one site to other sites. These combinations are already contained in dictkey; I just need to reorganize them. This is so I can pop off the shortest distance, and eventually get a list of the "nearest neighbor" to each site.

```
for i in np.arange(num_sites):
    lat1 = lat[i]
    lon1 = lon[i]
    site1=site[i]
    rat1 = lat1*np.pi/180.0
    ron1 = lon1*np.pi/180.0
    for j in np.arange(i+1,num_sites):
        lat2 = lat[j]
        lon2 = lon[j]
        site2= site[j]
        rat2 = lat2*np.pi/180.0
        ron2 = lon2*np.pi/180.0
```

## Calculate the distance using the Haversine Formula

```
        d = 2.0*np.arcsin(np.sqrt((np.sin((rat1-rat2)/2))**2 +
            np.cos(rat1)*np.cos(rat2)*(np.sin((ron1-ron2)/2))**2))

        # dist_arr[i,j] = 6371.0 * d

        dictkey[site1+"_"+site2] = 6371.0*d

temporary = set()
for key in dictkey: 
    parts = key.split("_")
    site_one = parts[0]
    site_two = parts[1]
    temporary.add(site_one)
for temps in temporary:
    candidates = dict()
    for key in dictkey:
        parts = key.split("_")
        site_one = parts[0]
        site_two = parts[1]
        if site_one == temps:
            candidates[site_one] = dictkey[key]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to achive it is to prepare candidates during calculating distance. Just prepare dict of candidates instead of dict_key:

```
candidates = {}
for i in np.arange(num_sites):
lat1 = lat[i]
lon1 = lon[i]
site1=site[i]
rat1 = lat1*np.pi/180.0
ron1 = lon1*np.pi/180.0
for j in np.arange(i+1,num_sites):
    lat2 = lat[j]
    lon2 = lon[j]
    site2= site[j]
    rat2 = lat2*np.pi/180.0
    ron2 = lon2*np.pi/180.0

    d = 2.0*np.arcsin(np.sqrt((np.sin((rat1-rat2)/2))**2 +
        np.cos(rat1)*np.cos(rat2)*(np.sin((ron1-ron2)/2))**2))


    distance = 6371.0*d
    if site1 in candidates:
        candidates[site1][site2] = distance
    else:
        candidates[site1] = {site2: distance}

    if site2 in candidates:
        candidates[site2][site1] = distance
    else:
        candidates[site2] = {site1: distance}
```

Solution above would give you dictionary candidates with dictionaries with distance to all other sites. It's of course double sized - it stores same data for 1234-> 4567 and 4567 -> 1234.

```
candidates.get('1234', {}).get('4567') == candidates.get('4567', {}).get('1234')
>>True
```

But as you see, it provides easy way of getting values.
If you need to get e.g. site with lowest distance to 1234:

```
import operator
closest_site = sorted(candidates.get('1234', {}).items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

taken from answer[1](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/613218/1673590)

closest_site will be tuple: `(<ID of closest site>, <distance>)`

Please write if you need more memory efficient solution. This is not optimal, because generate double sized data.

**UPDATE**

If you need to get ID of original site together with shortest distance site:

```
closest_site = (candidates.get('1234'),) + sorted(candidates.get('1234', {}).items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

then closest_site: `(<ID of original site>, <ID of closest site>, <distance>)`

Comment: Great, thanks! Is there a way to then have closest_site output the original site as well, so I know which site is the home and which site is the nearest one? Otherwise if I do something like candidates.get(site1, {}) I get all of the nearest neighbor IDs, but not the original site number. Very cool idea though, a dictionary of dictionaries!